# MapProxy doesn't start with EPSG:28992 while it starts and works fine with EPSG:4326

Tags: proj, mapproxy, centos

We are moving from Debian to CentOS and in that process we discover that MapProxy installation is turning out tougher in CentOS than it was in Debian.
One of the dependencies 'libproj' is not available as a CentOS package so I installed 'proj' which seems similar.

But when I try to start the MapProxy Instance it gives the following error stack:

```
[xyz@localhost spinmapproxy]$ sudo mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml
[sudo] password for xyz:
[2019-03-25 10:22:31,154] mapproxy.config - INFO - reading: /opt/spinmapproxy/mapproxy.yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/mapproxy-util", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 387, in main
    commands[command]['func'](args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 85, in serve_develop_command
    app = make_wsgi_app(mapproxy_conf, debug=options.debug)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/wsgiapp.py", line 110, in make_wsgi_app
    services = conf.configured_services()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 211, in configured_services
    return self.services.services()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1770, in services
    new_services = creator(service_conf or {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1857, in wms_service
    tile_layers = self.tile_layers(conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1789, in tile_layers
    for tile_layer in layer_conf.tile_layers(grid_name_as_path=use_grid_names):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/util/py.py", line 78, in wrapper
    cache[key] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1698, in tile_layers
    for grid, extent, cache_source in self.context.caches[cache_name].caches():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/util/py.py", line 78, in wrapper
    cache[key] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1445, in caches
    request_format=request_format,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 1339, in _sources_for_grid
    source = source_conf.source({'format': request_format})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 747, in source
    coverage = self.coverage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/util/py.py", line 78, in wrapper
    cache[key] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/loader.py", line 545, in coverage
    return load_coverage(self.conf['coverage'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/config/coverage.py", line 107, in load_coverage
    return coverage(geom or bbox, SRS(srs), clip=clip)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/srs.py", line 89, in SRS
    srs = _SRS(srs_code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/srs.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.proj = Proj(init='epsg:%d' % epsg_num)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 158, in __init__
    (proj_def, init, libproj.pj_strerrno(errno)))
mapproxy.proj.ProjInitError: error initializing Proj(proj_def=None, init='epsg:28992'): no system list, errno: 2
```

I didn't have to do any specific configurations in Debian, I simply followed the instructions on MapProxy installation website and everything worked fine but with CentOS it looks like it requires some more settings.

Please can I get help with how this could be solved?

Comment: Do you have proj4 or proj6? With the latter, the epsg file is removed, I think, in place of proj.db

Comment: "proj-4.8.0-4.el7.x86_64" is the installed package in my CentOS machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue and now MapProxy works fine with EPSG:28992.

Problem: In the CentOS installation of package 'Proj' in 'usr/share/proj' directory the file with the name 'epsg' is missing.

Solution: I copied the epsg file from my Debian machine's 'Proj'-installation-folder to CentOS 'Proj'-installation-folder.